# Custom UIBarButtonItem not working properly in iOS8

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uibarbuttonitem

I am setting up a custom UIBarButtonItem which is working fine for iOS 7 but with iOS 8 I am seeing the back icon of my next view controller in pagination showing up on current visible page. I have multiple view controllers in UIScrollView.

Please see my code below. If I try removing the negative spacer, it works fine but then back icon moves to right side and does not look good.

Please provide thoughts.

[image]

```
UIImage *backArrow = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];
UIButton *aBackButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
CGSize aBackButtonTextSize = [MyLocalized(BackButtonKey) sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:kFontSize17]];
aBackButton.frame = CGRectMake(kScreenOrigin, kScreenOrigin, aBackButtonTextSize.width + backArrow.size.width, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height);
aBackButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
[aBackButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[aBackButton setTitle:MyLocalized(BackButtonKey) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[aBackButton setImage:backArrow forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *aLeftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:aBackButton];
UIBarButtonItem *aNegativeSpacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
aNegativeSpacer.width = -8;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = @[aNegativeSpacer, aLeftBarButtonItem];
```

Answer (score 0):

hm ...
you can put another 'positive spacer' as the third left button to compensate the first one. anyway, it seems too complicated for me. the best way how to implement custom UIBarButtonItem is (as i can see) subclass UIBarButtonItem and 'internally' implement its behavior.